# How to enable autocomplete for a project with react-native modules in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I created a new project using the command npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module

When I open it in android studio, neither syntax highlighting, nor navigation, nor autocomplete work

It can’t even navigate to a class that is defined with code that uses it in one module, example on the screenshot

[image]